# How to prevent node related errors during initialize of a React Native app

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I removed my node installation via brew and followed the steps on the [React getting started page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content) to install iojs. Before I updated npm via brew also. React Native installs properly, but as soon as I try to init an app via

```
react-native init my_app
```

I get the following trace:

```
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: 404 response dowloading http://nodejs.org/dist/v2.3.4/node-v2.3.4.tar.gz
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js:251:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.onRequestResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:985:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:415:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:88:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:305:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/iojs/2.3.4/bin/iojs" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/jason/projects/dos/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v2.3.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Re-installation of `node-gyp` does not solve the issue.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with io.js and node-gyp. See this line in your logs:

```
Error: 404 response dowloading http://nodejs.org/dist/v2.3.4/node-v2.3.4.tar.gz
```

node-gyp tries to download v2.3.4 distribution from node.js site, but it's obviously not there since it's io.js. To fix this io.js is shipped patched npm. Unfortunately, if you update npm via `npm install -g npm` it will be broken again.

You can try `npm uninstall -g npm` but it seems to just wipe npm entirely, so you have to reinstall io.js.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is definitely the problem. Unfortunately when uninstalling node010, iojs AND npm, and re-installing iojs only, there is no npm available. Thats why I installed it via brew again. Could be an issue with the current iojs version I guess. Anyway, I switched to node010 and react native 0.8.0-rc works anyway